# Google Analytics Reporting API v4 returning separate data for the same URL with different capitalization (C#)

Tags: c#, google-analytics, case, case-sensitive, google-reporting-api

I'm using the Google Anayltics Reporting API v4 to query page views on my site, ordered by most viewed. I discovered that I'm getting duplicate entries, where the path is the same but the capitalization is different

```
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange()
{
    StartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
};

// Create the Metrics object.
Metric pageviews = new Metric {Expression = "ga:pageviews", Alias = "Pageviews"};

//Create the Dimensions object.
Dimension path = new Dimension { Name = "ga:pagePath" };

OrderBy orderby = new OrderBy {FieldName = "ga:pageviews", SortOrder = "DESCENDING"};

// Create the ReportRequest object.
ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
{
    ViewId = viewId,  
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { path },
    Metrics = new List<Metric>() { pageviews },
    OrderBys = new List<OrderBy>() { orderby }
};

List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
requests.Add(reportRequest);

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.
GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

// Call the batchGet method.
GetReportsResponse response = svc.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();

foreach (var report in response.Reports)
{
    var data = report.Data.Rows.Select(x => new AnalyticsPage
    {
        Path = x.Dimensions[0],
        Views = Convert.ToInt32(x.Metrics[0].Values[0])
    });
    pages.AddRange(data);
}
```

When I view my results, `pages[41]` is "/events/tech-knowledge" (3150 page views) and `pages[429]` is "/Events/Tech-Knowledge" (200 page views)

Is there something I can add to my query to make the API ignore case in the path field? I know I could modify my code to combine entries where the path.ToLower() is the same, but it would be better to get the API to return the data correctly

Comment: I am facing the same issue, when try to extract the data using GA4 runreport endpoint? Any latest enhancement on this? @Erica https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/runReport

Answer (score 0):

Checked the [Analytics API reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/), no such ready made filter. I suggest proceeding with your workaround.